# Magento : Display Configurable Product From Simple Product Url

Tags: product, configurable-product, event-observer, url-rewrite

I'm trying to load configurable product from my simple product url. I dont want to redirect on configurable product page.

www.example.com/textured-halter-dress-black-l.html is the simple product url
My simple product is not visible individually, thus www.example.com/textured-halter-dress-black-l.html will return 404 error.

www.example.com/textured-halter-dress.html is my configurable product url.

Thank you.

Comment: Fixed by following instructions from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607051/preselect-configurable-product-options-by-simple-product-url